# Type 'Any' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable' when trying to conform to an equatable generic Set

Tags: ios, swift, generics, set

I'm trying to create a base struct that supports a set of types (Int, Float, maybe string, possibly sometimes Vec4 matrix). I've built a base struct and conformed it to Hashable, made the type Equatable, but now I need to use this new struct in a Set.

This line:

```
struct AdjustmentSet: Set<BaseAdjustment<Any>>
```

where I declare the struct for the Set, is throwing

> Type 'Any' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'

Which of course is obvious in and of itself, but I don't know how to actually define a type here that works (I tried `T: Equatable`, `Equatable`, and nothing works).

```
struct BaseAdjustment<T: Equatable>: Hashable {

    var hashValue: Int {
        return displayName.hashValue
    }

    static func == (lhs: BaseAdjustment<T>, rhs: BaseAdjustment<T>) -> Bool {
        return lhs.displayName == rhs.displayName &&
            lhs.value == rhs.value &&
            lhs.isApplied == rhs.isApplied
    }

    var min: T?
    var max: T?
    var displayName: String = ""
    var value: T?
    var defaultValue: T?
    var isApplied: Bool = true

    init(min: T, max: T, displayName: String, defaultValue: T?) {
        self.min = min
        self.max = max
        self.displayName = displayName
        self.defaultValue = defaultValue
        self.value = defaultValue
        self.isApplied = true
    }
}

struct AdjustmentSet: Set<BaseAdjustment<Any>> {
    static var brightness   = BaseAdjustment<CGFloat>(min: 0, max: 1, displayName: "Brightness", defaultValue: 0)
    static var exposure     = BaseAdjustment<CGFloat>(min: 0, max: 1, displayName: "Exposure", defaultValue: 0)
    static var contrast     = BaseAdjustment<CGFloat>(min: 0, max: 1, displayName: "Contrast", defaultValue: 0)
}
```

---

Addendum:

I'm hopeful that with the introduction of `Opaque Types` in Swift 5, we can do away with this complexity by defining the set of type `some BaseAdjustment`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AdjustmentSet` has to itself be generic:

```
struct AdjustmentSet<T: Equatable>: Set<BaseAdjustment<T>> {

}
```

But then of course, `Set` is a struct, not a class or protocol, so it can't be subtyped like this.

Comment: Bah humbug. So how can I solve this using a set (or set-like protocol/struct)? I basically need a unique set of all of my BaseAdjustment instances.

Comment: @brandonscript Well what you have isn't a set, it's just a series of static variables. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Ultimately this set of properties will be displayed in an array, and will be added or removed at certain points. So, basically, like a set. But each property needs specific sub properties like in the struct. I could write all that, and I may have to, but if Set can do it, why would I want to?

Comment: @brandonscript Sounds like you need to wrap a set, not subclass it.

Comment: Care to point me in the right direction? I can’t find much helpful in the docs, or I’m not looking in the right place.

Comment: @brandonscript The general term for what I'm describing is "composition over inheritance". https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/protocol-oriented-programming-in-swift-daba92bc9c98